# Select element from elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to select an element after I selected more elements. I think it should be something like this, but this isn't working because `.is()` returns `true` or `false`.

Html:

```
<div class="bar a"></div>
<div class="bar b"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $el = $('.bar');
$el.addClass('active');
$el.is('.a').addClass('icon');
```

I could loop through `$el` but I hope there might be a easier/faster way.

Using `.eq(1)` is not an option as I don't know the order of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `filter()` to extract the elements which have `.a` assigned:

```js
var $el = $('.bar');
$el.addClass('active');
$el.filter('.a').addClass('icon');
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.icon {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar a">bar a</div>
<div class="bar b">bar b</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to add `icon class` on elements with `class a` which is simple.

`$('.bar').addClass('active')
 $('.a').addClass('icon')`